# How create custom methods on my models with moogose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

already, i want to call a method on my model, for compare the password given with the password encrypted on my database, im used a custom method on my schema, but appear the following error, when tried to execute the controller, i supose than i want to do, only can be used with "new" object, objects than already are on my database cant access to the method, thanks in advance for any help:

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k7qj.png)

1. models/User.js

> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> var mongoose, Schema, UserSchema, schemaOptions, bcrypt;
> mongoose  = require('mongoose');
> bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
> Schema = mongoose.Schema;
> schemaOptions = {
>     toObject: {
>       virtuals: true
>     }
>     ,toJSON: {
>       virtuals: true
>     },
>     timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
>     new: true,
>     runValidators: true
>   };
>
> UserSchema = Schema({
>     _id:{
>       type:Number,
>       unique: true,
>       index: true
>      },
>   provider:String,
>   id:{
>           type: String
>       },
>   displayName:{
>           type: String,
>           required:  [true, 'Scribe the Full name']
>       },
>   name: {
>           familyName:{type: String,required:  [true, 'Scribe the last name']},
>           givenName:{type: String,required:  [true, 'Scribe the first name']},
>           middleName:{type: String,required:  [true, 'Scribe the middle name']}
>          },
>   emails:[{
>           value:{
>                 type: String,
>                 unique: true,
>                 lowercase: true,
>                 index: true,
>                 validate: {
>                  validator: function(v) {
>                    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(v);
>                  },
>                  message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email!'}
>                 },
>         type:{
>              type: String,
>              lowercase: true
>            }
>     }],
>   email:{
>          type: String,
>          unique: true,
>          lowercase: true,
>          index: true,
>          validate: {
>           validator: function(v) {
>             return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(v);
>           },
>           message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email for autenticate!'
>         },
>          required: [true, 'Scribe a Email']
>         },
>   password: {
>              type: String,
>              required: [true, 'Scribe a password']
>             },
>   photos:[{
>           type: String  
>         }],
>   alias: {
>           type: String,
>           required: [true, 'Scribe the alias'],
>           unique: true
>          },
>   birthday:{
>            type: Date,
>            required: [true, 'Select a birthday']
>            },
>   idiom: {
>          type: String,
>          required: [true, 'Select a idiom']
>          },
>   country: {
>            type: Number,
>            required: [true, 'Select a valid country'],
>            min:1,
>            max:231
>        },
>    rolId:{
>        type: Number,
>        required: [true, 'Select a rol'],
>        default: 1
>    },
>   deletedAt: { type: Date, default: null }
> },schemaOptions);
>
> // Execute before each user.save() call
> UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
>   var user = this;
>
>   if(this.isModified('password') || this.isNew){
>       bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (error, salt){
>          if(error){
>              console.log(error);
>              return next(error);
>          } 
>          bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (error, hash){
>            if (error) {
>                console.log(error);
>                return next(error);
>            }
>            user.password = hash;
>            console.log("hashing the password!");
>            next();
>          });
>       });
>   }else{
>       console.log("the password dont changed!");
>       return next();
>   }
> });
>
> //metodo para autenticar la clave recibida
> UserSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password, next) {
>   bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(error, isMatch) {
>     if (error) {
>         //return next(error);
>         next(error);
>         return false;
>     };
>      //return next(null, isMatch);
>      next(null,isMatch);
>      return true;
>   });
> };
>
>
> module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
> ```

2. controllers/UserControllers.js

> ```
> 'use strict';
> var validator = require('validator');
> var User = require('../models/User');
> var Rol = require('../models/Rol');
> var config = require('../config/database');
> var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
>
> function login(req, res){
>   var params = req.body;
>     User.find({email: params.email},function (error, user) {
>         if (error) {
>            return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al devolver los marcadores del servidor'});
>         };
>
>         if (!user) {
>           return res.status(404).send({message: 'El usuario con el correo designado no se encontro!'});
>         }else{
>             User.verifyPassword(params.email, function (error, isMatch){
>                 if(error){
>                     console.log(error);
>                     return false;
>                 }
>                 if (isMatch) {
>                    var token = jwt.encode(user, config.secret);
>                    return res.status(200).send({token:'JWT '+token});
>                 }else{
>                    return res.status(403).send({message: 'La clave no es correcta!'});
>                 }
>             });
>            return res.status(200).send({token:user});
>         }
>     }).limit(1);
> }
> .
> .
> .
> module.exports = {
>     login, createUser, getUser, updateUser, deleteUser
> };
> ```

Comment: seems a typo. `user.verifyPassword` instead  of `User.verifyPassword`

Comment: thanks for the answered, already i tried it to, but apper the same issue